# Method with attribute as input parameter

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a simple example

```
  class Program
{
    static void DoProcessing()
    {
        TraceMessage("Hello from DoProcessing.");
    }

    static void TraceMessage(string message,

            [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
            [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
            [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("message: " + message);
        Console.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
        Console.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
        Console.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-',25));
    }

    static void Main()
    {

        TraceMessage("Hello from Main!");

        Console.WriteLine(new string('-',40));
        DoProcessing();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what is the purpose of using [CallerMemberName], [CallerFilePath], [CallerLineNumber] attributes as input parameters? And when we should mark our input parameters with attributes?

Comment: Have you tried googling those attributes?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange yes, it's obvious what do those attributes mean, but when should we mark our input parameters with attributes?

Comment: For more details read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653988.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**CallerMemberName** Allows you to obtain the method or property name of the caller to the method.

**CallerFilePath** Allows you to obtain the full path of the source file that contains the caller. This is the file path at the time of compile.

**CallerLineNumber** Allows you to obtain the line number in the source file at which the method is called.

These attributes belong to `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` Namespace, which provides functionality for compiler writers who use managed code to specify attributes in metadata that affect the run-time behavior of the common language runtime.

In your case your output will be

```
message: Hello from Main!
member name: Main
source file path: c:\Users\Saket\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleAp
plication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs
source line number: 35
```

Here you printing caller name which is `main()` and file path and line number which is 35 (`TraceMessage("Hello from Main!");`) . Hope it is clear.

Reference [system.runtime.compilerservices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @sergiy-lichenko Please mark the question answered so it wont appear unanswered.